# Logstash with elasticsearch input loops results and always gives the error ” Failed to parse request body ”

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I'm getting this error no matter how I tweak my very basic logstash configuration:
`Error: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Failed to parse request body"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Failed to parse request body","caused_by":{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Unrecognized token '**************': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@6d67a6bb; line: 1, column: 30]"}},"status":400}`

Even if I know there are only 8 "hits" in the results, it will keep outputting the 8 results over and over until I kill the logstash script, ES keeps restarting ... at first, I thought it was my query, but I keep getting the same error even with NO query at all:

```
input {
     elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["***", "***", "*****"]
      index => "index_name_here"
      user => "****"
      password => "******"
     }
}
filter {
}
output {
    stdout { 
        codec => json 
    }
}
```

also, I am running Ubuntu 16.04

any help would be greatly appreciated.  thank you!

Comment: How does your query look like? It's not showing in your configuration

Comment: With or without a query I get the same error

Comment: Which version of Logstash and ES are you using?

Comment: versions 5.3 for both

Comment: Can you remove the BASIC security and try again? What happens?

Comment: This is a bug. We are investigating it.

Comment: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/issues/413

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been identified as bug. Details [here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-elasticsearch/issues/62).

And a fix (at the moment pending review): https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-elasticsearch/issues/62

Comment: looks resolved ... any idea how I can try out the latest version of logstash-input-elasticsearch?  Do i just reinstall logstash or do I have to build the plugin/logstash locally?

Comment: ok, I got it working after reading the docs on using custom plugins!  Thanks for the help.  After installing logstash normally (following the docs) I, 1) cloned the elasticsearch-input repo directly into my home/user folder `git clone https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-elasticsearch.git` 2) edited my logtash gem file `sudo nano /usr/share/logstash/Gemfile` 3) replaced the existing elasticsearch input line with `gem "logstash-input-elasticsearch", :path => "/../../../home/ubuntu/logstash-input-elasticsearch/"` 4) ran a basic logstash configuration normally (no restart required)