# Test logstash with elasticsearch as input and output

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, nest, elasticsearch-plugin

I have configured logstash with Elasticsearch as input and output paramaters as below :

input

```
      {
         elasticsearch {
         hosts =>  ["hostname" ]
        index => 'indexname'        
        type => 'type'
        user => 'username'      
        password => 'password'
        docinfo => true
        query => '{ "query": { "match": { "first_name": "mary" } }}'    
       }
     }
```

output

```
  {
   elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["hostname" ]
    index => 'indexname'                
    user => 'username'
    password => 'password'    
    }
   }
```

My indexed data is as below :

```
    PUT person/person/3 
    { 
     "first_name" : "mary" 
    }
    PUT person/person/4
    { 
    "first_name" : "mary.m" 
    }
     PUT person/person/5
    { 
    "first_name" : "mary.k" 
    }
```

When I run below query on ES

```
   GET indexname/_search
   {
    "query": {
     "match": {
       "first_name": "mary"
               }
       }
      }
```

it returns

```
         {
   "took": 1,
     "timed_out": false,
       "_shards": {
         "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
         "failed": 0
            },
          "hits": {
             "total": 1,
            "max_score": 0.2876821,
             "hits": [
              {
               "_index": "person",
                 "_type": "person",
                   "_id": "3",
                "_score": 0.2876821,
             "_source": {
             "first_name": "mary"
                       }
                    }
                 ]
               }
             }
```

Although logstash pipeline has started successfully it does not log this query in ES as I had used query as "match": { "first_name": "mary"} in input section.

Comment: It seems your sourcing the same index as you're sinking documents to. What's your use case exactly? If the query doesn't yield any documents, then Logstash will not be able to load any documents either.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Are you sure you're searching in the `indexname` index and not `person`???

Comment: Ok.. person is indexname only. I had changed it indexname to hide its actual name. In actual scenario , I am using person only everywhere

Comment: Then are you sure about your username/password credentials?

Comment: Yes.. using same credentials I logged data in ES using filebeat as input

Comment: Can you remove the `type` field in your input as this is not the ES mapping type but some other Logstash field that's not related to ES. Also can you run your pipeline with the `--debug` flag and share the log output?

Comment: Removed the typed field and sharing log file with debug on.. Seems like logstash is able to connect to ES

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1h0itu9hGMtlDnM1luPVWErNKxIfTtXi9LObKnZqCjs4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Which version of Logstash do you have?

Comment: logstash version : 5.4.0

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Kn1f6hT3kw4v9NiecTsxWG8PhGbhn4SK1h1J4udDNck/edit?usp=sharing Logstash cofig file

Comment: You probably need to add `ssl => true` in your `elasticsearch` input config ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your ES runs on HTTPS, you need to add `ssl => true` to your `elasticsearch` input configuration

```
input {
   elasticsearch {
      hosts =>  ["hostname" ]
      index => 'indexname'        
      type => 'type'
      user => 'username'      
      password => 'password'
      docinfo => true
      ssl => true                                 <--- add this
      query => '{ "query": { "match": { "first_name": "mary" } }}'    
   }
}
```

Comment: It is giving below error                                                                                      Error: initialize: name or service not known
  Exception: Faraday::ConnectionFailed
  Stack: org/jruby/ext/socket/RubyTCPSocket.java:129:in `initialize'
org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1197:in `open'
D:/Sushil/logstash-5.4.0/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:763:in `connect'
org/jruby/ext/timeout/Timeout.java:98:in `timeout'
D:/Sushil/logstash-5.4.0/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:763:in `connect'

Comment: Where is ca_file located? How to get the path

Comment: Make sure to remove the `https://` scheme in your `hosts` parameter. Works better?

Comment: It is not throwing any error now but it is also not logging anything in ES after using search query

Comment: I am  able to log now in ES but it is logging continuously in my person index with _type logs.. So suppose if put query in input as query => '{ "query": {  "match": { "first_name": "mary"}}}' in output it is logging continuously in my index for mary result although I didnt query it . I am not able to understand how logstash works

Comment: In your output, you need to add `document_type => "person"` and it will work.

Comment: Seems like it is a bug https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-elasticsearch/issues/62

Comment: That issue concerns the input plugin, not the output one. Do you get a similar error?

Comment: Yes.. I also get the same error. What can be the resolution?

Comment: It's not clear, earlier you said it worked but it wasn't indexing with the right mapping type. What happened since?

Comment: I thought it worked as it was indexing on ES. But then I realized it is only logging my query continuously .. same issue like this one.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43194114/logstash-with-elasticsearch-input-loops-results-and-always-gives-the-error-fai

Comment: Gotcha, then you can either downgrade or wait for a fix :-)

Comment: Downgrading logstash seems like good option :).. Anyways thanks for the help

Comment: I am now trying to connect ES 5.2 version since version 5.3 and above are not supported but is giving below error  Error: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?                                                                     My input configuration ES {
    hosts =>  ["9c809727c1f161596b7ab1dd35feef58.us-east-1.aws.found.io:9200"]
 index => 'nehgs'   
 user => 'USER'  
 password => 'PASS' 
    docinfo => true
    ssl => true  query => '{ "query": { "match": { "first_name": "mary" } }}'}

Comment: Since you're using port 9200, you need to set `ssl` to false

Comment: Getting below error after setting ssl to false Error : Attempted to send a bulk request to elasticsearch' but Elasticsearch appears to be unreachable or down

Comment: My mistake :) .. My output cluster was using port other than 9200 and I had set ssl to false..setting ssl to true removed the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144346/discussion-between-user3013365-and-val).